# Generalizations of the Gauss circle problem

Tags: number-theory, gaussian-integers

[The Wikipedia article on the Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) states that, if there are $N(r)$ lattice points of radius less than $r$ from the origin, then we know that $|E(r)|=|N(r)-\pi r^2|=O(r^{131/208})$.

Do we know whether this bound holds if we put the center of the circle at an arbitrary point in the plane rather than at a lattice point?